# SUSY particles as Dark Matter

Tags: supersymmetry, dark-matter, mssm

In SUSY, why is only the neutralino considered the best candidate for dark matter, why not the other SUSY particles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be a dark matter candidate, a particle needs to be stable, or at least long lived. In SUSY theories [LSP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lightest_Supersymmetric_Particle) (Lightest Supersymmetric Particle) is stable (if R-parity is conserved). There are models where gravitino is LSP, so it is also a good candidate.

Answer (score 0):

The dark matter particle also needs to be either neutral or have a very small charge (much smaller than that of an electron or quark), in order to be "dark". So in SUSY it can't be the superpartner of any of the charged particles, but the neutralino is a good candidate as it has zero electric charge.